# How do I detect when an element in an array is empty in C#? (When empty, element = 0)

Tags: c#, arrays, computer-science, element

I have an array of 5 integers, from 1 to 5. My assignment tells me I need to be able to detect whether atleast one element in the array is greater than zero. Only if ALL elements are empty, would I say that var isEmpty is true, and then return the value.

**Code:**

```
public static bool is_empty(int[] S, int n)
{

    bool isEmpty = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        if (S[i] != 0)
        {
            isEmpty = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: You linq-ing?  `return S.All(x => x == 0);` Done.

Comment: @Eminem his method sucks and is buggy.  He reports an empty array when only the last element is 0, not when all of them are.

Comment: Side note: if " 5 integers, from 1 to 5" is true condition, than method does not even need to iterate array - all elements are by definition not equal to 0 :)

Comment: We do your homework and you earn the credit. How does that work? *Feels jipped*

Comment: Okay I have highlighted my answer, thank you to everyone who took part in this post, it really helped. However though, I am finding it difficult to see why my code was totally wrong, despite the fact the code I now have works?

Comment: You're comparing against every value, but really only remembering the *last* value you checked.  If S[2] is non-zero it sets isEmpty to `false`, but then if S[4] is 0, then isEmpty gets set back to `true`, so it acts like your entire array is empty.  S[4] is the only value that ends up mattering.

Comment: Thank you, that is so much clearer now. This site can be very helpful, and a great response time.

Comment: @JamesShaw In all seriousness I have been working extremely hard on my own to get this far mate, I'm not some student who can't be bothered to do his work. I spent 30 minutes looking at my awful answer trying to figure out how to improve it in a way that works.

Comment: Greater than 0 or not equal to 0? Your question does not match your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as it considers only the last element in the element in the loop. Try this: Return that the array is not empty once you found a non-empty element; otherwise, return that all elements are empty:

```
public static bool is_empty(int[] S, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        if (S[i] > 0) // negative values still count towards "being empty"
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is probably what the prof was getting at--exiting execution of a method quickly.  A technique every developer should learn.  And to *hell* with those SESE jerks.

Comment: He said greater than 0, not != 0 (like his code). Maybe wanna update

Comment: @Evorlor: you deserve a reputation point for this comment. Thank you! Incorporated your spotting into the sample code.

Comment: Hey guys. I had word from my professor that the code you originally made does not work. Now you have updated it, would this work?

Comment: Hey @parkie1995, the current version is updated due to an error which you have in your code. You had stated "at least one element in the array is greater than zero" not unequal. The `if` statement reflects this. What you should always do is testing your code before you "deliver" it. Don't wait for your professor to find bugs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you have the input parameter n. So I've removed it. And instead I've used a foreach loop to loop through every element in the array.

```
static bool IsEmpty(int[] S)
    {
        foreach (int x in S)
        {
            if (x != 0)
            {
                return false; //If any element is not zero just return false now
            }
        }

        return true; //If we reach this far then the array isEmpty
    }
```

Comment: Up-vote. We don't know whether the `n` parameter was there for a purpose. In respect to the question though it is indeed of no relevance. Nice spotting.

Comment: I recommend not using a capital letter for a parameter name, but good work.

Comment: I was just keeping with the sample code for consistency. I also get infuriated by bad casing by developers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think by `you don't need variables` your teacher means you don't need the bool `isEmpty`,  You can use LINQ like others are saying, but I doubt you know what that is yet.

Per your requirements, you can say that "if I encounter any non-zero value, I have all the information I need to return a response".  If I check all values, and have not found any non-zeros, I also know how to respond then.  So try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   
    if (S[i] != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bool isEmpty = false;
int count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   if(S[i] == 0){
      count++;
   }
}
isEmpty = (count==n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
S.Any(x => x != 0);
```

This should give out true if any of the element in array is not equal to 0.

similarly, you can explore the option of All in case you need to check all the elements of an array.

```
S.All(x => x == 0);
```

so your code will be

```
public static bool is_empty(int[] S)
{
    // return true if no element is 0
    return !S.Any(x => x != 0);
    // or use
    return S.All(x => x == 0);
}
```

better still you don't need to create this method either, as you can directly call this statement from where you are calling this method (unless its called from multiple places).